# Проблема с макросом VBA в Outlook 2013

Tags: vba

Добрый день! Есть вот такой вот макрос, который позволяет весь выделенный текст превратить в 14 Times New Roman черного цвета. Хотелось бы его доработать так, чтобы он сам выделял автоматически текст письма, форматировал его, а также подчеркивал нужные слова красным цветом. Где можно почитать и есть ли уже готовые строчки кода? Спасибо заранее!

```
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document
Dim objSel As Word.Selection
On Error Resume Next

Set objItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
        If objInsp.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
            Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
            Set objWord = objDoc.Application
            Set objSel = objWord.Selection

   With objSel
        .Font.Color = wdColorBlack
        .Font.Size = 14
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
   End With

        End If
    End If
End If

Set objItem = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing
Set objSel = Nothing
Set objInsp = Nothing
```

Comment: Расплывчатая постановка задачи. Например: в какой момент планируете запускать макрос? Когда набрали все письмо? В чем заключается форматирование письма (какие параметры форматирования? Шрифт? Отступы? Выравнивания?)? Как собираетесь определять нужные слова для подчеркивания красным? Как это "красное" должно выглядеть?
Приведите для начала вид письмо до начала работы макроса, а затем после.